# echo javascript function with php variables as arguments

Tags: php, javascript

In test.php:

```
<?php
$result = "test";
echo '<script type="text/javascript">parent.showThanksDiv(\"<?php echo $result;?>\");</script>';
?>
```

and in test.html

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
 function showThanksDiv(text){
      document.getElementById("myThanksDivtext").value = text;
    }
</script>
```

That's not working. It seams Im not passing php variables correctly. Any ideas?

Comment: why did I get downvoted?! My question is legit, clear and helpful for newbie to php. Care to explain?

Comment: Well, for starters, neither the failure(s) nor the *generated HTML* were provide .. also, there are many similar duplicates. Also, take time to ensure there are no trivial spelling mistakes, especially in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the PHP to:

```
<?php
$result = "test";
echo '<script type="text/javascript">parent.showThanksDiv("' . $result . '");</script>';
?>
```

You don't need to wrap the PHP variable in `<?php` and `?>` since you're still in PHP.

Comment: mm That didn't work. When I do parent.showThanksDiv("test") that work

Comment: @Kam - I removed a pair of `\\` from my original post. Did you try the revised version?

Comment: Do spaces make a difference!? because I remembered trying "'.$result.'" before and it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

I guess you wanted to do something like that:

```
<?php
$result = "test";
echo '<script>parent.showThanksDiv("' . $result . '");</script>';
?>
```

Or to be more secure, I'd suggest to use `json_encode()`:

```
echo '<script>parent.showThanksDiv(' . json_encode($result) . ');</script>';
```